# UITextField delegate method not being called (shouldChangeCharactersInRange)

Tags: ios, input, keyboard, uitextfield

This UITextField delegate method is not being called even I changed the text in the textfield.
This happened when the keyboard language is set to Japanese/Chinese input and if I choose the words from the suggested list of words.

```
- (BOOL) textField : (UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange : (NSRange) range replacementString : (NSString *) string
```

I am not sure if this is a bug in iOS.

Does anybody encounter the same problem??

Comment: It sounds like a bug of iOS. What version of iOS are you using? Dose this delegate get invoked if your are inputing English?

Comment: I found this with the simulator, which is most probably 4.3. This delegate is invoked when it is English. It did not get invoked when you choose the word from suggested list, as in iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think this is a bug in iOS 4.x and it seems to have been fixed in the iOS 5 beta.

Due to the NDA about iOS 5 I can't tell more about it. Hope this help.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer is useful, a vote up or select it as the correct answer would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe not a bug in iOS 4.x.Even in iOS 9.x,this situation still exists.
For Japanese/Chinese or any other language that can  choose the words from the suggested list of words above the keyboards,this delegate method

```
- (BOOL) textField : (UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange : (NSRange) range replacementString : (NSString *) string
```

would not be called.The text of UITextfield is appended by the choosed word directly.

A workaround is to use `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(checkForTextfield:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

The affected text field is stored in the object parameter of the notification. The userInfo dictionary is not used.

```
-  (void)checkForTextfield:(NSNotification *)noti{
    UITextField* textField = noti.object;
    //do whatever you want with the UITextfield
}
```

And don't forget to remove self from `NSNotificationCenter` when dealloc   :

```
- (void)dealloc{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```